# SQL. BigQuery. DATE_DIFF A in B

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datediff

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE tests.segments (`date` date, ClientID STRING(6), SegmentID int)
```

With data

```
INSERT tests.segments VALUES ('2018-01-31' ,'A11111', 2), ('2018-02-28' ,'A11111', 2), ('2018-03-31' ,'A11111', 1), ('2018-04-30' ,'A11111', 1), ('2017-11-30' ,'B22222', 1), ('2017-10-31' ,'B22222', 1), ('2017-09-30' ,'B22222', 3), ('2017-09-30' ,'C33333', 1), ('2017-10-31' ,'C33333', 1)
```

I need to select DATE_DIFF for each ClientID in SegmentID
I know how to select it for ClientID or SegmentID separate

```
SELECT SegmentID, DATE_DIFF(DATE(MIN(date)), DATE(MAX(date)), DAY) as days_diff
FROM tests.segments
GROUP BY SegmentID
```

And how to do it without SQL :)
Please help.

Comment: can you give an example output with this input table? It is easier to understand that way. I can help you write the query

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "how to do it without SQL"? Are you looking for a solution using the likes of Python Pandas, etc.? Also providing an example of the expected output will be really helpful.

Comment: @Regressor, thank you! Lol, it is simple, I have overworked :D

Comment: @RiccoD, I mean, that I know, how to solve it with R and haven`t known how to do it with SQL. Thanks for your participation!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for this

[image]

But here is the query to achieve using the clientId in the group by clause. Let me know if this is the expected output.

```
SELECT SegmentID, clientid, DATE_DIFF(DATE(MIN(date)), DATE(MAX(date)), DAY) as days_diff
FROM tests.segments
GROUP BY SegmentID, clientid
order by SegmentID, clientid
```